# How to detect an arrived sms message in IPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to detect an arrived SMS in code? and how can I auto check if it contains specific strings? for example I wanna send SMS to the Iphone which contains "specifString" and I want the receiver Iphone auto open my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot, get a notification when a person receives a SMS, but you can enter a special url in that SMS that then would launch your application when clicked.

In your Info.plist you have to define some key-value pairs:
[image]

And then your app is launched when url like this is clicked:

```
yourapp://?foo=1&amp;bar=2
```

as you can see, you can pass parameters to your app.

In your app you get a special event, when your app is launched from an url.

**4.1 and earlier:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
  // Do something with the url here
}
```

**4.2 and later **

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
{
    // Do something with the url here
}
```

More details in documentation:  ["Implementing Custom URL Schemes"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html)

**Edit after WWDC Keynote 06.06.2011**

New API **iMessaging** now supports messaging on iPad and also receipts to know if your message has been delivered.

Answer (score 2):

You can not achieve what you are trying to do. Apple restricts this kind of things, because this amounts to spying on the user who uses your application.

Comment: hmmm... so how can I send data and get an alert on my app? for example I want to get text trhough sms or wifi and get alerted in my app?

Comment: You can't use SMS, you have to use PushNotification.